# Excel Countifs with Wildcards

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

When using =countifs on Excel I have a list and I am trying to see how many instances in that list contain a specific number. For example I have 990432 (in cell A5 of on Workbook) as my specific number and a list (in column A of another Workbook) of numbers below. Currently everything is formatted as "General". I have tried using the formula:

```
=countifs($A:$A, "*"&A5&"*")
```

- 990432-1345183
- 990432-134511235
- 15612-990432

I've tried changing the number format to Text and it worked, but I need them as numbers for another formula I am running on the data.

Comment: it works for me.  Not sure why it does not work for you, unless there is some decimal on the number that are not shown in A5.

Comment: No decimals on the number. Not quite sure what it is. I tried it in a brand new blank workbook and it didn't work either.

Comment: what does it return?  "Does not work" is a little vague.

Comment: It just returns 0.

Comment: Could it be that there is an empty space in cell A5? Try `=COUNTIFS($A:$A,"*" & TRIM(CLEAN(A5)) & "*")`

Comment: Perhaps the three examples you give are not fully representative of your data. If in fact you have numerics like 123**990432**456 in the search column, then `COUNTIFS` with a wildcard will not show a match, since the example I give is a numeric.